# In Scala how do you update a property of an object within an array of objects, the object being selected by the user

Tags: scala

In Scala how do you update a property of an object within an array of objects, the object being selected by the user?

The object is being previously selected by the user via its ID number (which is the first field of the object). I would like to update the last field of the object.

My code:

```
    case class Order(oId :Int, dt :String, cId :Int, sta :String) {
    var orderId = oId
    var dateTime = dt
    var customerId = cId
    var status = sta
  }


        def main(args: Array[String]) {
        //New Orders
        var o1 = new Order(1, "13 JUN 2016 12:30", 1, "New")
        var o2 = new Order(2, "13 JUN 2016 12:32", 2, "New")
        var o3 = new Order(3, "14 JUN 2016 12:30", 3, "New")
        var o4 = new Order(4, "14 JUN 2016 12:32", 4, "New")

        var orders1 = Array(o1,o2,o3,o4)

        //print list of orders
        val printList = readLine("Type yes to print a list of orders?")

        if ((printList == "yes") || (printList == "Yes")){
          orders1.foreach { println }
        }

        val orderNo = readLine("Which order would you like to view?").toInt

        for(i <- 0 to orders1.length - 1) {
          if(orders1(i).orderId == orderNo) {

            println(xxxx)

            val newStatus = readLine("Type picked to update status")

            if (newStatus == "picked"){

              println (newStatus)

              orders1(orderNo).status = newStatus

              orders1.foreach { println }
            }

          } else {

          }
        }


      }
```

Comment: Hi. I think you should add some code to your answer. It will allow us to have a better understanding of what you want to do and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Please paste some sample codes about the object with property, the array of objects, and the ID number selection.

Comment: If you intend to search for object in a collection, you probably shouldn't use `Array` as a collection. Using `Array` mean, that in a worst case you would have to iterate over all elements in `Array` before you find object you're looking for. You can find object faster if you put them in a collection that support fast searching/lookup operation - like [`Map`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/maps.html): `val orders = Map(0 -> Order(0,...), 1 -> Order(1,...)), ...` and then `order(1)` (where `1` is `id` of order you want to retrieve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scala's `Array` wouldn't allow you to add or remove elements by but it allows changing the referenced elements at a given position:

```
val a = Array[Int](1,2,3)
a(1) = 0
```

However if you want to change the property of an object, that property should be mutable. For example, if the objects contained by your array are instances of ordinary case classes as:

```
case class C(x: Int, y: String)
val a = Array(C(1,"hello"), C(2,"bye"))
```

Then you won't be able to change, lets say, property `y` without creating a new element sharing the same value for the other properties:

```
a(1) = a(1).copy(y = "good bye")
```

In the line above, you'll be creating a new instance of C and assigning it to the position 1.

On the other hand, if your elements are instances of classes with mutable properties such as:

```
val b = Array(new MC(1,"hello"), new MC(2,"bye"))
```

You won't have any problem to change their properties:

```
b(1).y = "good bye"
```

**EDIT:** Based on your code:

`Order` defined as:

```
case class Order(ordId_ :Int, datetime_ :String, custId_ :Int, status_ :String) {
    var orderId = ordId_
    var dateTime = datetime_
    var customerId = custId_
    var status = status_
  }
```

Have 8 attributes. That is duplicated attributes. If you want to make you case class attributes mutable you should mark them as `var` in the case class attributes list:

```
case class Order(var ordId :Int, var datetime :String, var custId :Int, var status :String)
```

Instead of duplicating them.

Comment: Ok thank you very much, Yes im already using a case class. I've changed my declared objects and the array they are stored in, to vars. But when I print out the list of objects after the update, the update doesn't show

Comment: @JHubbard Changing the array reference to `var` is of not use in this case. You're always referencing the same array whose elements you are changing.  Can you provide your code? Note also that if you're copying the whole array into a new one with the changes, you won't "see" these changes in the original.

Comment: ok thank you, I am using the same array. I have uploaded my code below

Comment: @JHubbard The problem with your code is that you have 2 attributes sets at `Order`. Those ending with underscore (immutable attributes) and those declared as vars. Case classes "arguments" are not just their constructor arguments but also the declaration of `val` attributes.

Comment: Oh thank you for pointing this out. I have got rid of the underscore, but the update still doesn't show

Comment: @JHubbard Check my edit. There are other issues with your code but they are not related with your problem. Scala is highly compatible with Java but is not Java, I'd recommend you to read some tutorials or books: _Programming in Scala, Scala for the impatient, Scala for Java developers..._

Comment: @JHubbard Try with `case class Order(var ordId :Int, var datetime :String, var custId :Int, var status :String)`

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt see your edit at first, I will try that now